# moving li's so that i can make a new list

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
// makes an li inside of a ol when a button is pressed

function addLi() {

    var txtVal = document.getElementById('txtVal').value,
        listNode = document.getElementById('list'),
        liNode = document.createElement("li"),
        txtNode = document.createTextNode(txtVal);

    liNode.appendChild(txtNode);
    listNode.appendChild(liNode);

};

function addoutp() {

};
```

I don't know what to put inside this function to move the inputted text over to another part of the screen separately...

Answer (score 0):

You were very close. Just adding some HTML that matches your selectors in the JS code and it started working. I also added a check to make sure there was a value before adding to the list and also a reset to clear the input value after the text gets added to the list (`txtVal.value = '';`).

```js
// makes an li inside of a ol when a button is pressed
function addLi() {
  var txtVal = document.getElementById('txtVal'),
    listNode = document.getElementById('list'),
    liNode = document.createElement("li"),
    txtNode = document.createTextNode(txtVal.value);
  
  if (txtVal.value) {
    liNode.appendChild(txtNode);
    listNode.appendChild(liNode);
    // clear the input
    txtVal.value = '';
  }
};
```

```html
<input id="txtVal" type="text" />
<button onclick="addLi()">Add to list</button>
<ol id="list"></ol>
```